# React state updating but rendering late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've tried almost every solution similar to my problem, yet none is working. I have a simple state and changing the value of this state in a function as like below, `handleOnClick` is calling in a button's `onClick` event. I'm also using Router(if it's change something);

```
    import { useState} from "react"
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
    
    const Buton = () => {
    
    let x = "";

    const [lowerState, setLower] = useState("")
    
    const history = useHistory();
    
    const handleOnClick = () => {
        x = document.getElementById("my_input").value.toLowerCase();
            
        setLower(x)

        console.log(x) //this prints the current value
        console.log(lowerState) //this DOES NOT prints the current value, but 
                                // when I put another text into the input and click
                                // to button, it prints the first value I put here
            
        history.push('/test', {params : lowerState})
    };
      
     .
     .
     .
    return (...)
}
export default Buton
```

Now `x` is a value that returns from an `input` HTML element. When I set this value as a state and console log, it doesn't print the value first, when I put something in input again, then it prints the first value. So it's like it's coming 1 step behind.

I've used `useEffect()` , I did put a second parameter to `setLower` as `console.log(lowerState)` and other things on the internet that people suggested, but none is working. Every time, the state is coming 1 step behind. How can I make this state changes immediately?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the value of an input in a user event function, the best way (and least buggy) is to bind your input value to local state and then just reference that state in your callback function.

Please try to avoid imperatively pulling values from the DOM using `getElementById` etc. Here's what I mean:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

// This will keep everything updated until you need to use it
handleChange(event) {
  setValue(event.target.value);
}

// Then just grab whatever is in local state
handleClick() {
  history.push('/test', {params : value});
}

return (
  <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
  // Your button is here too
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you call `setLower(x)` it is not an async call. So it doesn't wait. That's why you get the 1 step before value in your state right after setting the value.

Official doc - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setLower(x)`, it doesn't immediately update the `lowerState`. The new value will be available the next time it renders. Because of that the  `console.log(x)` "works" (since it uses the new value that you gain as a parameter) but `console.log(lowerState)` uses the old value that hasn't updated to the state yet at that point.

If you want `history.push('/test', {params : lowerState})` to work, then you need to use the `x` there instead of `lowerState`. Or call it within a `useEffect` with the `lowerState` and having `lowerState` as a dependency parameter to the hook.

Comment: I got "React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "handleOnClick" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function" when I use useEffect(), that's why it didn't work when I tried other solutions.

Comment: Hooks are component level things. They're never meant to be called within functions (other than the component main level itself).

Answer (score 0):

### **This is expected behaviour since [React is updating state in a batch](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)**

Which mean that the state only gets an update after an eventHandler/function is finished

If you want to do some condition, wrap your logic inside a `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (lowerState === "your-condition-value") {
    history.push("/test", { params: lowerState });
  }
}, [lowerState]);
```

Or in your case, just use the variable directly:

```
const handleOnClick = () => {
  x = document.getElementById("my_input").value.toLowerCase();
  history.push("/test", { params: x });
};
```

**You should not worry about that since your app still working as expected**

Comment: I got "React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "handleOnClick" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function" when I use useEffect(), that's why it didn't work when I tried other solutions.

Comment: You should put the useEffect inside the body of the component, for example after you defined handleOnClick

Comment: @GLHF Put your useEffect right under this line: `const history = useHistory();`

Comment: Okay I got your point, but now when I put history.push inside the useEffect, it immediately routing to the "/test" url. It acts like [lowerState] has always been changing. It doesn't wait for button click, so I can see the current value in console.log now but it immediately routing me to "/test" url. If I put history in handleOnClick, then it's again 1 step behind

Comment: Yeah, then try to use my 2nd example. just use directly `history.push` in your `handleOnClick`

Comment: But I want to use state variable, that's the point :) I understood the logic behind useEffect, but why does it acts like [lowerState] changing always? Shouldn't it check first if it changed then executes the codes inside useEffect?

Comment: For your current code example, I don't think useState is suitable here, If you want to test useState, please look for another example: Ex: input value

Answer (score 0):

So i would like to suggest that use useRef if need for reference only object which may not causing rerendering. also using let x= "" is not correct, you should write code immutable way

```
const Buton = () => {
    
   const lowerCaseRef = useRef("")
    
    const history = useHistory();
    
    const handleOnClick = () => {
        lowerCaseRef.current = 
        document.querySelector("#my_input").value.toLowerCase();
        console.log(lowerCaseRef.current) //this DOES NOT prints the current value, but 
                                // when I put another text into the input and click
                                // to button, it prints the first value I put here
            
        history.push('/test', {params : lowerCaseRef.current})
    };
      
   
    return (...)
}
```

Comment: Well this actually works, the only thing worked so far. I wonder, is `useRef()` holds the variables like a state? Because my main point was passing values to another URL using states. How does `useRef` acts like?

Comment: `useRef` is not like state. It is just a box to hold values like any other variable. React does not track updates to the `current` property on refs and will not re-render when the ref value is changed. This is why you shouldn't use refs to hold values like input text - it leads to difficult issues when things get more complex. What you have right now may work, but there are two main issues. One, you're not binding your input to state, and two, you're reaching into the DOM as part of a user event. You're treating DOM as the source of truth instead of your react state and this will lead to bugs.

Comment: yes it not like state, and one should bind value to input if it controlled, but for uncontrolled component you may bind ur value as it wont needed render everytime i.e. onchange

Comment: Yes, but using uncontrolled inputs is rarely a good idea outside of a few exceptions. It's recommended to use controlled inputs unless your use case requires you to use uncontrolled, and wanting to reduce renders is not a great reason given that they are cheap. The React team outlines the recommendations here, controlled so that React handles state: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: The Above Problems wont need useState, as far i understand to saw this, for input yes controlled component is good, but its vary. one should go with any approach that make thing simple.